# Children or Young Adult Fantasy Story

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm currently on the lookout for a book that my boyfriend read while he was in primary school, he started in 1999, and it was in their school library, so he might have read it around 2006-2007, although the book could have come out earlier as we live in Denmark.

He read the book in Danish. (However it could have been translated)

It might be part of a series, but all the happenings are in one book only.

He doesn't remember the title of the book, nor the over-all plot, but he remember it starting with:

1. An adult female character who is the caretaker of the main character being hanged.
2. The child, a boy, teaming up with an adult male character.

And then he vaguely remember something about a tower, it's a fantasy story set in a medieval setting.
- He says it seemed like the setting of might and magic
- Maybe the main character was fleeing.

I know it is not a lot, but I hope that it can be enough, to bring us closer, as he's been searching for the book for the last year or so with no luck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Was the book in English or Danish? Also, could you ask your boyfriend for more details? As it stands, only someone who has read the book is likely to recognize the description given.

Comment: What about it was fantastical?

Comment: There is a list of questions you can ask him at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: I tried asking him the questions, I really appreciate it, and I'm so sorry it's so vague. I just felt like this might have been our best try to finding the book.

Comment: It reminds me of a flashback scene in Stephen King's 'The Gunslinger' which is the first novel in his Dark Tower series.

Comment: Roland, the main character comes from Gilead which is described like a Medieval setting. Someone gets hanged, I seem to remember it being a cook and the Gunslinger finds a boy, but that may be in the second book "The Drawing of the Three". The series is about Roland, the Gunslinger chasing a man called 'The Man in Black' toward a Dark Tower that is sort of the center of the universe in that series. I don't know if that's right, but that's what the description reminded me of

Comment: @JoshuaA Aah, thank you so much! Is there a female character that the main character is romantically involved with? Seems like it's starting to ring a bell!

Comment: In book 4 ("Wizard and Glass") Roland has a love interest named Susan (who dies), and I believe that's also the book in which Roland's mother (...adult female who is the caretaker...) dies (...but not by hanging).  But I really doubt this is the book (series) the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Michelle, ehh no the lead female is Susannah and she falls in love with one of the other main male characters, Eddie. The little boy's name is Jake. Susannah is in a wheelchair, I don't know if that helps with remembering. The bad guy's name is The Man in Black (aka. Walter, or Randall Flagg) They are filming a movie on the first book, The Gunslinger now with Idris Elba as Roland and Matthew Mcconaughey as The Man in Black.

Comment: @ gowenfawr, yea he would have had to have read the first four books at least to make all those details match up and I just feel like he would have remembered that. It's just what it reminded me of.